# Trying get the dominant frequency from accelerometer data

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, fft, android-sensors

I'm working on an app that will return the frequency of vibration that a phone is experiencing using the accelerometer.

It's for my own personal use .. and just to gain experience in DSP and using sensors in my phone.

So, I grabbed some sensor data and wrote the absolute value to an array. My next step was to use an FFT to try and get the dominant frequency. And that's where I'm lost.

My end goal, really, is just to determine if data is periodic or not in real time. So, if I'm going about this all wrong, please point me in the right direction.

If I'm going in the right direction, where am I making mistakes in my code? I'm new to android and java, and it's possible I'm making some gross logical errors as well. If I can take an array, perform an FFT on it, get the dominant frequency in real time, and display that result ... I'm all ears.

Code snippet below: (the array fftData is full of garbage data)

```
int N = 1024;
        double[] magnitude = new double[N/2];
        double[] fftData = new double[]{
                0.0176,
                -0.0620,
                0.2467,
                0.4599,
                -0.0582,
                0.4694,
                0.0001,
                -0.2873};
        double[] fft = new double[N*2];
        double max_index=-9999999;
        double max_magnitude = -9999999;
        float sample_rate = 59.98f;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            fftData[i] = AbsVal;
        }
        DoubleFFT_1D fftDo = new DoubleFFT_1D(N);
        fftDo.realForwardFull(fftData);

       // I'm lost here ...

        double frequency = /* not sure what to do here either */;
        Strength.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(AbsVal)) + " \u00b5T");
        field.setText(String.valueOf(frequency));
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first the result of FFT is 'two dimensional' in regards to frequency,  fftData[i] and fftData[i+1] both contains values for the frequency i (or fftData[i] and fftData[i+N/2]), but one is in real another in img domain (or one for sin another for cos function). 
You need to convert the fft spectrum to 1D, which is called power spectrum PS[i] = fft[i]^2+fft[i+1]^2 (in your case you can ingore that the value is square of PS).
So read your FFT library manual how the FFT results are represented (if the indexes=0,1 belong to first frequency or is it 1 and 2, os is it 1 and N/2+1).

Then you are looking for the hights peek (value) in your PS table. The index for the highest will be your frequency.

And finally you want to calculate the 'real' frequency which depends on your sampling interval and number of points.

P.S. Beffore FFT you need to lineary detrend your data (Apache math, SimpleREgression to find the slope and interception and remove them from your data).